Why did the maiden flight of Kairos fail?
On March 13, 2024 the maiden of Space One's launch vehicle Kairos was automatically destroyed by it's Flight Termination System 5 seconds after launch. At the time, the company stated that they were investigating it, but since then I have not been able to find any report as to what was the issue. Why did the Flight Termination System automatically terminate the maiden flight of Space One's Kairos vehicle 5 seconds after launch?

Even those in Japan are asking, and there has been no public announcement, and the official site has no new news. So, as of this day, you'll know as much as anyone else.

According to Space News, “the rocket’s autonomous flight termination system was triggered by underperformance of the rocket’s first stage motor.”
